# Login functionality in ASP.NET Core without database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I wanted to do a login functionality without a database.

I have referenced the of login functionality in this link : https://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2019/06/implementing-login-functionality-in.html

In the `AccountController` how do I restructure the post function to do like:

```
if username = admin && password = admin with the rememberme then system will allow the user to login with Session Cookie
```

In here :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
                model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid Login Attempt");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

If I cannot do that, then how do I need the login functionality to get the table values based on the references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the standard authentication model this way.

You can implement your idea by using cookies:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
    
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    string id = Request.Cookies["id"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        return View();

    if (id.Equals("A48FFAEC-FD0E-4DED-B66E-87014762CC3D"))
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(LoginModel login)
{
    var validUsers = new List<LoginModel>
    {
        new LoginModel {Username = "admin", Password = "admin"}
    };

    if (validUsers.FirstOrDefault(f => 
            f.Username.ToLower() == login.Username.ToLower()
            && f.Password == login.Password) != null)
    {
        string uniqueId = "A48FFAEC-FD0E-4DED-B66E-87014762CC3D";

        CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions {MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(7)};
        Response.Cookies.Append("id", uniqueId, option);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
    }

    ViewBag.Error = "Invalid account credentials";
    return View();
}
```

You can use a file to store credentials and use GUID to generate new unique identifiers for different users and implement more dynamic and own user management :

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    string id = Request.Cookies["id"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        return View();

    if (! System.IO.File.Exists(Resources.ValidIdentifiersFileName))
        return View();

    var validIds = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Accounts.txt");
    if (validIds.Contains(id))
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(LoginModel login)
{
    var validUsers = new List<LoginModel>
    {
        new LoginModel {Username = "admin", Password = "admin"}
    };

    if (validUsers.FirstOrDefault(f => 
            f.Username.ToLower() == login.Username.ToLower()
            && f.Password == login.Password) != null)
    {
        string uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText("Accounts.txt", uniqueId + Environment.NewLine);

        CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions {MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(7)};
        Response.Cookies.Append("id", uniqueId, option);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
    }

    ViewBag.Error = "Invalid account credentials";
    return View();
}
```

- Note that this implementation is very simple and not completely secure and qualified, for security reasons it's better to use standard and qualified authentication methods that handle different security path.

Comment: OK thanks. Btw , do you have some statement like logout or check if user has login  based on the cookies method ?  Like if SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User) that can check user had signed in or not. For the log out , does it have some alternative way like this below :    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
    }

Comment: For checking the user is logged in you can easily write a filter inherited from "IAuthorizationFilter" and validate user cookies to know user is logged in and for logout simply remove cookies.